# concatenate cell contents with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

the original dataset in Excel look like this:

[image: original dataset]

But I want to transpose **for example** the cells A3:A4 to B4:C4. In Excel I only need to copy the cells and then right click in cell B4 and click on transpose the copy cell. But due to 100k rows, I need to find a good solution how to do that.

One problem is that between the cell, I have text contents like "first section", "second section", "third section", and I don't want to transpose it.

Means for the first section, it should only consider A3 and A4 and so on.

Here is the picture, how I it should be looks like.

[[image: this is what I want][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSNKe.png)

I record the macro, but I don't know where I should tell them with "IF-Clause" that it should only consider everything except the yellow cells.

```
Sub transponieren()
'
' transponieren Makro
'

'
    Range("A3:A4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'test' you're probably looking for is the `IsNumeric()` test.  The following code suggestion assumes your data is on Sheet1, and the numbers are actually numbers and not text.  There's probably a more elegant solution, but this does work:

```
Sub transposeNumbers()
Dim c As Range, LastRow As Long, TopN As Long, LastN As Long

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A3:A" & LastRow)

    If IsNumeric(c.Offset(-1, 0)) = False Then
    
        TopN = c.Row
      
    Else
    
        If IsNumeric(c.Offset(1, 0)) = False Or c.Row = LastRow Then
        
            LastN = c.Row
            
            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(TopN, 1), Sheet1.Cells(LastN, 1)).Copy
            c.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, transpose:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        End If
    
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: hi kevin thanks, but in the line  Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(TopN, 1), Sheet1.Cells(LastN, 1)).Copy the vba stopped with runtime error 1004. Could you check please, thanks in advance.